# how to make abbr tag to work only for ellipsed text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.ellip {
    width: 300px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  cursor: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellip">
<input type='checkbox' value='"+a.a+"' name='radio' title='"+a.b+"' class='"+a.c+"'><span id='"+a.b+"'><abbr title='"+a.a+"'>"+a.a+"</abbr></span><i class='fa fa-pencil'  aria-hidden='true' ></i>
</div>
```

I have some data inside a div and when it exceeds the div length, the text inside it will be ellipsed and the complete text of that particular item should be displayed using `<abbr>`. But now `<abbr>` is working for all data. How can I make it work for only ellipsed text? Can I achieve this using javascript or jquery ?

Comment: Your CSS lacks specificity.  Have you tried using `.ellip abbr[title] { }` instead of `abbr[title]`.  That would target only an `<abbr>` that is a direct descendent of `.ellip`

Comment: In my code abbr[title] is used just to remove the underline caused by <abbr>... and I tried .ellip abbr[title] { } but its not working.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? The dotted underline styling of `<abbr>` is not universal.

Comment: @RobertC Chrome

Answer (score 0):

As we had discussed in comments, the issue here is specificity.  The CSS you list in your original post targets `<abbr>` throughout the document, where your goal is to only target `<abbr>` found within a wrapper of `.ellip`.

The solution then, is to ensure that your CSS is specific enough:

```css
.ellip {
    width: 300px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ellip abbr {
  border-bottom: none;
  cursor: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellip">
  <abbr title="This should not be underlined in Chrome">This should not be underlined in Chrome</abbr>
</div>

<abbr title="This should be underlined in Chrome">This should be underlined in Chrome</abbr>
```

Again, you're going to see different results in different browsers depending on how that browser has chosen to style the `<abbr>` element.  Some (like Safari) offer no styling at all, while others choose to apply `smallcaps` or various underline effects.